# XML reading string value between tags

Tags: c#, xml

Suppose, I have the follwing XML:

```
    <SplitterLayoutDataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/SplitterLayoutDataSet.xsd"> 
        <SplitterLayout> 
            <SplitterName>mainSplitContainerControl</SplitterName>
            <SplitterPosition>0.2213375796178344</SplitterPosition>
        </SplitterLayout> 
    </SplitterLayoutDataSet>
```

I need a way how to get SplitterPosition value, in this case: 0.2213375796178344. Is there any receipt to reach this solution without using Linq-to-XML, or letting combine these ways? This XML is designed in SplitterLayoutDataset.xsd file. Or how do I read the field *SplitterPosition* of that file directly with C# tools? 
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you like LINQ to XML?

Comment: Agree with @OleksandrPshenychnyy - this would be absolutely trivial in LINQ to XML.

Comment: If you dislike LINQ-to-XML there is `XmlDocument` or you can even go directly with `XmlReader`... But if you want manual string operations answer you must prove that you understand whole XML specification before such answers can be given :)

Comment: I like LINQ to XML but it will crash the program logic. Otherwise, it has to be totally rewritten

Comment: @Krill - That sounds like there's a bigger problem.

Comment: @Bobson The problem doesn't exist anymore :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `XmlDocument` and `SelectSingleNode`:

```
var xml = @"
<SplitterLayoutDataSet xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/SplitterLayoutDataSet.xsd""> 
   <SplitterLayout> 
       <SplitterName>mainSplitContainerControl</SplitterName>
       <SplitterPosition>0.2213375796178344</SplitterPosition>
   </SplitterLayout> 
</SplitterLayoutDataSet>";

//Create XmlDocument
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

//Create NamespaceManager (for XPath)
var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("dn", "http://tempuri.org/SplitterLayoutDataSet.xsd");

//Get inner text of SplitterLayout/SplitterPosition
var xPath = "//dn:SplitterLayout/dn:SplitterPosition";
Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath, nsMgr).InnerText);
```

Or based on @AlexeiLevenkov's suggestion, you could eliminate the `NamespaceManager` by using the following XPath:

```
var xPath = "//*[local-name()='SplitterPosition']";
Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath).InnerText);
```

Of course, you can also use `XDocument`:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = @"http://tempuri.org/SplitterLayoutDataSet.xsd";
Console.WriteLine(xdoc.Descendants(ns + "SplitterPosition").First().Value);
```

Or using `XDocument` and `XPathSelectElement`:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var xPath = "//*[local-name()='SplitterPosition']";
Console.WriteLine(xdoc.XPathSelectElement(xPath).Value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm gonna try that :)

Comment: +1... also two versions are not searching for the same element... and XPath could be simply `"//*[local-name()='SplitterPosition']"` (or add namespace-uri check too) to match "xdoc.Descendants" call and avoid all namespace setup.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Is there a way to get `SplitterPosition` using `XDocument` without specifying the `XNamespace`?

Comment: You can use [XPathSelectElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083.aspx) to select nodes with XPath in `XDocument`.